# How to call UDF in DataStage?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, etl, datastage

I want to call an Oracle user defined function through DataStage jobs. That function will return value that will update the target table.

I have tried using Stored Procedure stage but I was not able to map function parameters through this stage.

Which DataStage stage should I use to call the function ?

Comment: From where are you pulling the input parameters to the function?

Comment: What was exactly the problem? Did you wrap your function in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it from the 'Before SQL' or 'After SQL' tab of the OCI stage. I'm guessing you need to do it before.

You can also script it and use SQL*Plus 'before job' to do the same.